# Is there a way to store get a counter of failed tests in pytest?

Tags: python, pytest

After running all the test I would like to receive a counter of all tests run, failed tests and successful tests. This information shall later on be used by another tool which parses the data.

Comment: I see that this question has a similar answer however the question is completely different. I was searching this exact thing and nothing turned up neither on Google nor here. I appeal to the decision as the other answer was also done by hoefling which kind of feels like promoting your own answers so that people only see your own answer. If this is true I will leave this community.

Answer (score 1):

My answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61525815/3771575) can be modified to include a counter. Once again modify / create the `conftest.py`

Add

```
from collections import OrderedDict
test_results = OrderedDict()


def pytest_configure(config):
    """Intial setup of test_results counters"""
    global test_results
    test_results['amount_of_failed_tests'] = 0
    test_results['amount_of_tests'] = 0
    test_results['amount_of_successful_tests'] = 0
```

And modify `pytest_runtest_makereport` as follows:

```
@pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True, hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    """The actuall wrapper that gets called before and after every test"""
    global test_results
    outcome = yield
    rep = outcome.get_result()

    if rep.when == "call":
        full_name, test_file, test_name = get_current_test()
        test_results['amount_of_tests'] += 1

        if rep.failed:
            test_results['amount_of_failed_tests'] += 1
            # return the last error msg either by pytest.fail or from any exception raised
            test_results[test_name] = "Failure"
            test_results[test_name_msg] = f"{call.excinfo.typename} - {call.excinfo.value}"
        else:
            test_results['amount_of_successful_tests'] += 1
            test_results[test_name] = "Success"
            test_results[test_name_msg] = ''
```

The result can once again be accessed in the end:

```
def pytest_unconfigure(config):
    """Called when pytest is about to end. Can be used to print the result dict or 
    to pipe the data into a file"""
    print(test_results)
```

Comment: Never use globals in hooks. For example, when running the tests in parallel via `xdist` the `test_results` dict will remain empty, producing wrong results.

Comment: In my case it is perfectly fine since I ran once on test after another via pytest.main(). xdist is a special case which does not have to be considered by a normal pytest run